# Stack Exchange Privacy Policy and third-party data collectors

Tags: discussion, privacy

[Gnip](https://www.gnip.com/) is a data collection company, that sources from a [variety of websites](https://www.gnip.com/realtime/data-collector/) and services, **including Stack Overflow**. Is this third-party data collection from SO in line with the current Privacy Policy? Is SE selling data to Gnip or is the latter simply "scrapping" the service?

Some excerpts form the [Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy):

> When we collect your personal information, we’ll tell you how we’re using it, any types of third parties to which we might disclose it, (other than moderators or “agents,” such as vendors or contractors, who are only processing such information for us or at our direction),

Have they told us that SE is selling this information to Gnip? If not, then maybe SE is operating under the "other" category above. But do they just "process" such information? If Gnip is selling such information to their clients, then that is probably not the case.

On top of this, the policy states the "ways we may use personal information you provide us":

- To allow you to register for our web sites, online communities and other services, and to administer and process those registrations
- To communicate with you about our products, services and related issues
- To evaluate the quality of our products and services, and to enhance your experience on our web sites
- To help employers find or contact users who post profiles on the Jobs site
- To maintain and administer our web sites and comply with our legal or internal obligations and policies
- **To transfer information to others as described in this policy** or to satisfy our legal, regulatory, compliance, or auditing requirements

I imagine the Gnip contract refers to the latter ("To transfer information to others as described in this policy"), which is quite a broad and tautological phrase. A more explicit recognition to this would be appreciated.

Then, the policy says that SE will not sell personal data except on "rare events", and that such situation is "hard to imagine":

> Other than on Jobs, we won’t share your personal information with non-agent third parties unless we are required to do so by law, or if we believe in good faith that disclosure is reasonably necessary to protect our property, rights or those of third parties or the public at large. **It is possible that we may, on occasion, buy or sell assets from or to other companies.** If that should occur, user information is typically one of the assets that get transferred. Similarly, if Stack Exchange or most of its assets were acquired, or in the unlikely event that we go out of business or enter bankruptcy, user information could be transferred or acquired. You should be aware that such events can occur, and that if it does, the buyer may continue to use your personal and non-personal information, but only as set forth in this policy. **Other than in these rare circumstances, Stack Exchange will not rent or sell potentially personally identifying information to anyone.**
>
> **It’s hard to imagine that we would ever consider collecting, let alone sharing, sensitive information with a non-agent third party,** but if such a day should come, we will first give you the opportunity to explicitly consent (opt-in) to such disclosure or to any use of the information for a purpose other than the one for which it was originally collected or previously authorized.

Has actually such "opt-in" situation happened? Personally, I don't remember doing that, unless it was part of the ToC when you agreed to use the service, a rather "obscure" way to "opt-in", I would say. Also, if this situation is already happening, then maybe the current Policy is misleading and should be updated to reflect that **such "hard to imagine rare event" has actually happened.**

Finally, SE states that they will ensure third party users to comply with this policy:

> In the unlikely event that we should discover that an agent is using personal information in way that conflicts with this policy, we will take all reasonable steps to stop them immediately.

Can SE confirm that Gnip complies with this policy?

Comment: Well, it looks like they're a provider around already public datasources... http://support.gnip.com/sources/stackoverflow - you can get a lot more using the SO API/Datadumps yourself than they give access to...

Comment: I wouldn't see it so much as what they're doing as "data collection" - more like just taking what SO provides (no personally identifiable data unless someone's put it in posts/their profile etc...) to *anyone* via datadumps/the API and redistributing it as they're allowed to... albeit it in a rather uninteresting way...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks. That sounds like an answer. Interested in converting it to one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't have a relationship or arrangement with Gnip. However, they answer your question (rather simply) themselves:

> [Gnip provides managed access to StackOverflow’s public API via the Data Collector.](http://support.gnip.com/sources/stackoverflow/)

They also go on to say:

> In addition to Twitter data, Gnip offers firehose and managed access to APIs from other popular social media sources.

It makes me sad when people imply that we're a social media source, but I don't see anything nefarious here :) They can access (and cache) our API just like anyone else.

While they don't explain why it might be advantageous for someone to use their service over our API directly (perhaps less throttling?), the returned data sample seems rather straightforward and in compliance with our CC BY-SA license. At this point, they fall into the group of folks that simply remix and reuse our content.

We did [update our terms of service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa) some time ago to more explicitly state circumstances under which we'd take very deliberate action to stop bad data-scraping actors, but simply remixing content is expected use of the site.

Comment: May I ask if there is any personal data sharing agreement between SE and any other data collector/broker? Or that is a separate question?